# How to install .apk file from local storage programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-install-apk

I want to install the .apk file which is stored in my local storage programmatically.

Here is my code,

```
StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    builder.detectFileUriExposure();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download/goodbox-1.0.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag android returned a intent error!
    startActivity(intent);
```

But this code is not working.

My compile and target SDK version is 30.

Please help me.